# Count not modified correctly on user action in React state (redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I have started using redux. I have multiple product cards and each one has + and - button to increase and decrease the quantity of the product, managing the state with `react-redux`. The problem is that when I click on + button to increase the item quantity decreases first and then increases and when clicking the - button it increases first and then decreases. My code attempt is shown below.

this is `store.js` file:

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import itemQtyReducer from "./counerSlice";

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: itemQtyReducer,
  },
});

export default store;
```

this is redux Slice file:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

//below fetchdata is an action
export const fetchData = createAsyncThunk("fetchData", async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://192.168.1.11:3000/product/getproduct"
  );
  //   console.log(response.data.data);
  return response.data.data; //this response.data.data will be set in action.pyload.
});

const itemQtySlice = createSlice({
  name: "itemQTY",
  initialState: { isLoading: false, products: [], isError: false },
  reducers: {
    incrementItem: (state, action) => {
      const { productId } = action.payload;
      const product = state.products.find((item) => item._id === productId);
      if (product) {
        product.count++;
      }
    },
    decrementItem: (state, action) => {
      const { productId } = action.payload;
      const product = state.products.find((item) => item._id === productId);
      if (product && product.count > 0) {
        product.count--;
      }
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchData.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
      state.isError = null;
    });
    // builder.addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
    //   state.isLoading = false;
    //   state.data = action.payload;
    // });
    builder.addCase(fetchData.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.products = action.payload.map((product) => ({
        ...product,
        count: 1, // Initialize item count to 0 for each product
      }));
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchData.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log("Error", action.payload);
      state.isError = true;
    });
  },
});

// export const { incrementItem, decrementItem } = itemQtySlice.actions;
export default itemQtySlice.reducer;
```

this is component file:

```js
import React from "react";
import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import classes from "./CarouselBestSeller.module.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {
  fetchData,
  incrementItem,
  decrementItem,
} from "../../redux/counerSlice";

const CarouselBestSeller = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // const data = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
  const { products, loading, error } = useSelector((state) => state.counter);

  // console.log(products);

  const handleIncrement = (productId) => {
    dispatch(incrementItem({ productId }));
  };

  const handleDecrement = (productId) => {
    dispatch(decrementItem({ productId }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchData());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const options = {
    loop: true,
    nav: false,
    items: 4,
    slideBy: 1,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000,
    margin: 10,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 7000,
    smartSpeed: 2500,
    dots: false,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
      },
      1000: {
        items: 4,
      },
    },
  };

  const item = [
    {
      _id: "648839702e8eca8532b71b6b",
      category: "non veg",
      product_name: "veg biryani",
      profile_url: "/images/products/food.jpg",
      gross_weight: "250",
      net_weight: "300",
      mrp: "100000",
      selling_price: "500",
      sort_descri: "sdjfbjwb",
      strong_instruction: "sdmbfsj",
      meta_title: "skdhfiwhe",
      meta_keyword: "s6dd",
      meta_descri: "jegdhdnd8cs",
      __v: 0,
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className={classes.bestseller}>
      <div className={classes.productrow}>
        <OwlCarousel {...options}>
          {products.map((item) => (
            <div className={classes.productCard} key={item._id}>
              <div className={classes.cardImgContainer}>
                <img
                  className={classes.cardImg}
                  src={"http://192.168.1.7:3000" + item.img}
                  alt="food"
                />
                <div className="counterproduct">
                  <div
                    className="campare2"
                    onClick={() => handleDecrement(item._id)}
                  >
                    -
                  </div>
                  <div className="count2"> {item.count}</div>
                  <div
                    className="campare2"
                    onClick={() => handleIncrement(item._id)}
                  >
                    +
                  </div>
                </div>
                -
              </div>
              <Link className={classes.cardTitle} to="/products">
                {/* Premium Boneless Chicken Breast Fillet */}
                {item.product_name}
              </Link>
              <span className={classes.cardWeight}>
                {item.gross_weight} gms
              </span>
              <div className={classes.cardPrice}>
                <div className={classes.actualPrice}>
                  <span>₹</span> <span>{item.mrp}</span>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.discountPrice}>
                  <span>₹</span> <span>{item.selling_price}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <span className={classes.timing}>Tomorrow 6-8 pm</span>
            </div>
          ))}
        </OwlCarousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarouselBestSeller;
```

I was expecting the normal behaviour on clicking the + and - button.